# How to add WebRequestTraceFilter in spring-boot-2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I used to have the following configuration, but as of `spring-boot-2.0` the `WebRequestTraceFilter` is no longer available.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filter(WebRequestTraceFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setUrlPatterns("subpath/*"));
    return registration;
}
```

What is the proper replacement of the filter above?

Answer (score 1):

In 2.0 tracing is intentionally less flexible as per comment in the below GitHub issue link.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12953

I was able to implement something similar by extending `HttpTraceFilter`